# optimizer in tensorflow does not work in nonlinear works

Tags: tensorflow

I am new to tensorflow and have tried to implement a simple one-layer linear network similar to https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/beginners

```
  x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, IN_SIZE], name="input") 

  W1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([IN_SIZE, OUT_SIZE]), name="Weight1") 
  b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([OUT_SIZE]), name="bias1") 
  y = tf.matmul(x, W1) + b1 

  y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, OUT_SIZE], name="target") 

  cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean( 
      tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y)) 
  train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-3).minimize(cross_entropy)
```

The program works as expected and I have no problem on that. However, I try to add another layer but only found the `W1,b1,W2` learnt are all zero matrix, and only the bias `b2` contains nonzero values. Below is my modified network

```
  x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, IN_SIZE], name="input") 

  W1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([IN_SIZE, L1_SIZE]), name="Weight1") 
  b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([L1_SIZE]), name="bias1") 
  y = tf.matmul(x, W1) + b1 

  W2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([L1_SIZE, OUT_SIZE]), name="Weight2") 
  b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([OUT_SIZE]), name="bias2") 
  y = tf.nn.relu(y) 
  y = tf.matmul(y, W2) + b2 

  # Define loss and optimizer 
  y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, OUT_SIZE], name="target") 

  cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean( 
      tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y)) 
  train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-3).minimize(cross_entropy)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that if you initialize the weight matrices before a relu with zeroes the gradients will always be zero and no learning will happen. You need to do random initialization.